# Why is Ext$(-;k) =0$ when $k$ is a field

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've seen the result repeatedly that $\text{Ext}(-,k) =0$ when $k$ is a field. I am yet to see a justification of this however.

Comment: What ring are you working over?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_k(A,B)$ is zero as soon as $A$ is a projective $k$-module, or also if $B$ is an injective $k$-module.

- On the one hand, all modules over a field are free (in other words, all vector spaces have a basis), and a free module is always projective.
- On the other hand, all modules over a field are injective too, because if you have a submodule (really, a vector subspace) $B \subset E$, then you can extend a basis of $B$ to a basis of $E$ and thus find a complementary subspace.

Both of these arguments show that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_k(V,k) = 0$ for all vector spaces $V$.

---

However, it is not true that if you have a field $k$ which is a module over some ring $R$, then $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(A, k) = 0$ for all $R$-modules $A$. For example $\operatorname{Ext}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{F}_2, \mathbb{F}_2) = \mathbb{F}_2$ even though $k = \mathbb{F}_2$ is a field. You need to be careful about what your base ring is.

Comment: On the other hand, the field need not be projective as a module over an arbitrary $k$-algebra, so it is quite possible for that Ext (when not as $k$-modules) to be non-zero.

Comment: (heh, I commented before the edit. Nice addition).